# Why did barragan turn against Aizen before he dies?

Tags: bleach

In the fight against Hachi and Soi-Fong after being mortally wounded, Barragan the way he called them ants throughout the fight why didn't he want to take out Hachi or Soi-Fong my reasoning being he should have wanted to take out the people who costed him his life but instead suddenly turned against Aizen all of a sudden? Why did he do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He decided to take on the one who cost his pride than his life. He was initially the God-King of Heuco mundo and the arrogant overlord of all hollows until Aizen with Gin and Tousen made his entry and dethroned him from Las Noches with a display of his Shikai. Barragan had merely been reduced to being a henchman of a renegade shinigami from that of a king of hollows which hurt him deeply and towards his last breath decided to take out Aizen who had brought him this dishonor.

Comment: Yes, more than that, he lost his throne to a shinigami. As a hollow it should be even worse.